# How to use Java optional operator to map more than one subtype

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to use the java Optional operator to avoid nullchecks like:

```
if(outher != null && outher.getNested() != null &&
          outher.getNested().getInner() != null && outher.getNested().getAnotherInner() != null)
```

I looked up some tutorials at the internet + Java cheatsheet but didn't find how to resolve the:`outher.getNested.getInner() != null && outher.getNested.getAnotherInner != null` part.

So how to do that correctly something like:

```
Optional.of(outher)
.map(Outher::getNested)
.map(Nested::getInner)
.map(Nested::getAnotherInner)
.isPresent();
```

would be awesome

Comment: Your code seems to be good, just replace `Optional.of` with `Optional.ofNullable` because `outer` can be `null` too. So what is the problem you have with that code?

Comment: Make your getters return Optional, and use flatMap instead of map.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the answer

Comment: possible this link :http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/03/15/avoid-null-checks-in-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.map(Nested::getInner)` returns an instance of Inner, but it should return Outer.

My suggestion is:

```
Optional.ofNullable(outher)
.map(Outher::getNested)
.map((outer) -> outer.getInner() == null ? null : outer)
.map(Nested::getAnotherInner)
.isPresent();
```

Not sure about flatMap, because you should map an entity on itself

Comment: I would change the second `map` operation by a: `.filter(outer -> outer.getInner() != null)`

Comment: @MarkusSchreiber what is SafeNavigationOperator? Anyway, that would give an exception if any object along the way is null.

Comment: The SafeNavigationOperator is a class which he wrote xD -> no it works awesomely

Comment: The solution from ekaerovets works too which is awesome (-:

Comment: @MarkusSchreiber the only way this class can work is to catch NPE in a try block while executing lambda. Looks far from optimal

Comment: It does the same as
`Optional.ofNullable(outher)
.map(Outher::getInner)
.map(Inner::getOne)
.isPresent() && Optional.ofNullable(outher)
.map(Outher::getInner)
.map(Inner::getTwo)
.isPresent()` -> which is the obvious way I didn't think of ):

Comment: @ekaerovets I like your solution more

Comment: `.map((outer) -> outer.getInner() == null ? null : outer)` is just a verbose variant of saying `.filter(outer -> outer.getInner() != null)`…

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a way to use `flatmap` if you really want to :

```
 boolean result = Optional.ofNullable(outer)
            .map(Outer::getNested)
            .filter(x-> x.getInner() != null)
            .map(Nested::getAnotherInner)
            .isPresent();
```